# Value of CheckBox not posted to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a page which contains a matrix where a user is linked to different skills.
This is displayed as a page containing checkboxes.
What I would like is to save only the rows that have actually changed.
Therefor I added an "IsChanged" property which gets set to "true" when a user changes the value for a checkbox.

I have the following code:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.EmployeeList.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeList[i].Id" />
    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="EmployeeList[i].IsChanged" name="IsChanged" id="IsChanged_@Model.EmployeeList[i].Id" />

    <tr>
        <th scope="row">@Model.EmployeeList[i].Name @Model.EmployeeList[i].Surname</th>
        <th scope="row">
            @Model.EmployeeList[i].Location
        </th>
    @for (var j = 0; j < Model.EmployeeList[i].SelectedSkillList.Count; j++)
    {
        <td>                
            <label class="label">
                <input asp-for="EmployeeList[i].SelectedSkillList[j].IsSelected" data-changedHidden="IsChanged_@Model.EmployeeList[i].Id" type="checkbox" class="label__checkbox" />
                <span class="label__text">
                    <span class="label__check">
                        <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </label>

            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.EmployeeList[i].SelectedSkillList[j].Prefix)
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
}
```

When I check one of the other checkboxes wihtin the @for, the checkbox EmployeeList[i].IsChanged for the given row is checked.
This works fine and I can see that happening on my page.

However when I save the post the data, the value for the IsChanged-checkbox, doesn't get included in the post. It always remains false.

Where did I make a mistake?
Can anyone help me?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsChanged" id="IsChanged_1" data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsChanged field is required." value="true">
<input name="EmployeeList[0].IsChanged" type="hidden" value="false">
```

This is the model :

```
        public List<Core.Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<MachineTypeSpecs> MachineTypeList { get; set; }

    public CompetenceMatrixModel(IEmployeeData employeeData, IMachineTypeSpecs machineTypeSpecs)
    {
        this._employeeData = employeeData;
        this._machineTypeSpecs = machineTypeSpecs;
    }
```

The Core.Employee contains the IsChanged property.

Comment: Can you post what actually appears in the browser HTML for that <input> field?

Comment: Also, can you include your Model?

Comment: If you specify `asp-for` do you also need to specify the `name` for the checkbox? I thought that helper would have done that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok stupid me, removing the name corrected the problem. Thanks to @Craig H